# protect files via .htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-headers

Might have been discussed before, but I just can't find a quick and clean solution.

1) I have a bunch of files in my `/data/` folder: .jpg, .gif, .mp4, .pdf, etc.

2) I want to create a `/data/.htaccess` file that will catch each request and redirect it to a PHP processor, e.g.:

```
/data/filename.jpg -> /data/processor.php?file=filename.jpg
```

3) the `processor.php` will do as follows:

3a) Check if you have a valid `$_SESSION['logged_in'] == TRUE`

3b) Send corresponding headers

3c) Send file data

Ideally the .htaccess redirect won't change the browser's URL, so all the current file requests will stay valid AS LONG AS you are logged in.

**EDIT:**

As it was suggested the better approach would be to keep my files outside of the web root. Thus, I'm going to only leave `/html/data/processor.php` and move all media files (like .jpg and .mp4) to `/media/` outside of web root.

Comment: You are best off putting files like this outside of the web root. The files will not be able to be downloaded directly then and php can access the files no problem. Then just pass an id to php that corresponds to a file or use htaccess and redirect all requests under a path to php and parse the path to get a filename.

Comment: agree about keeping files outside of web root! good point +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the URL in the browser, then what you want is a URL rewrite instead of a redirect.  You .htaccess file should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^data/(.+) /data/processor.php?file=$1 [L]
```

This will cause requests to `/data/filename.jpg` to actually request `/data/processor.php?file=filename.jpg` without doing anything to the URL in the browser.  Then your processor.php script can take over from there.

Keep in mind that you must have mod_rewrite enabled within server's configuration.

Something else to consider.  You may or may not want to keep these files outside of the document root depending on which is more important: security or usability.  If the ,htaccess portion fails for whatever reason, do you want the files to by default be accessible or not?  In other words, do you give the user the benefit for the doubt as to their access rights in this case?  If so, leaving the files where they are would be best as the URLs will just work and deliver the files the user is expecting.  If you want to error on the side of not granting access, then moving the files outside of document root would be good so that they are not accessible without the mod_rewrite rules going through your script.

**/data/processor.php**

Here is a sample of what your processor could look like:

```
<?php
// Get MIME Type
    $finfo     = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
    $mime_type = finfo_file( $finfo, $_GET['file'] );
    finfo_close( $finfo );

// Send headers
    header( "Content-Type: $mime_type" );
    header( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $_GET['file'] );

// Send file data
    readfile( $_GET['file'] );
?>
```

Be sure to include a path along with `$_GET['file']` if necessary depending on where you end up locating your files.

Comment: Is there a known PHP script I should be using? Like checking for Session variable is no biggie, but match up each extension with a proper header, and then output file contents. How do I do that?

Comment: @Geo if you check out the php manual page for [header](http://www.php.net/header), in the user comments there are a few examples that should work well. Something like [this](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175)

Comment: @Geo: I'd recommend following the script mentioned by @Jonathan Kuhn with one minor exception. Instead of trying to match the extension to a mime type, I'd recommend checking out the `FileInfo` functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php.

Comment: I would appreciate the actual code in the answer, so I can accept it. I'm pretty clear on the `header` part. What about output file contents?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some sample code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution that worked out for me. Just in case it might be useful for anyone. Thank you @Nick Coons!

HTAccess file **/html/media/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Processor file **/html/media/index.php**

```
<?php

require_once '../config/config.php';

// must be logged in
if ( ! @$_SESSION['logged_in']) exit('Access denied. You are not logged in.');

// check if file exists
$file = dirname(dirname(getcwd())) . '/media/' . @$_GET['file'];
if ( ! is_file($file)) exit('404');

// Get MIME Type
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
finfo_close($finfo);

// Send headers
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

// Send file data
readfile($file);

/* End of file */
```

Media folder **/media/**

```
.png and .jpg files are stored here outside of the web-root
```

Now request to `/html/media/bike.png` only works for logged in users.